# Cannot connect to PPTP VPN on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn, pptp

I am fairly a new user to Ubuntu and Linux distributions and installed 18.04 LTS on vmware workstation. i already have a VPN connection that is working fine from a Windows machine. but if i configure the same account on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, it give me error **"vpn connection failed. activation of network connection failed "** Below is the /var/log/syslog error.

```
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[709]: <warn>  [1605258602.8234] vpn-connection[0x5642253585b0,89532b81-a556-43b5-9714-36997a8048d9,"KPVPN",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu nm-pptp-service[2643]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu pppd[2656]: Terminating on signal 15
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[709]: Terminating on signal 15
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[709]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp 115.x.x.x --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-2643 (pid 2659) terminated with signal 15
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu pppd[2656]: Child process /usr/sbin/pptp 115.x.x.x --nolaunchpppd --loglevel 0 --logstring nm-pptp-service-2643 (pid 2659) terminated with signal 15
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu pppd[2656]: Connection terminated.
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[709]: Connection terminated.
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1605258602.8374] vpn-connection[0x5642253585b0,89532b81-a556-43b5-9714-36997a8048d9,"KPVPN",0]: VPN service disappeared
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu pppd[2656]: Exit.
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu gnome-shell[880]: Removing a network device that was not added
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu pptp[2665]: nm-pptp-service-2643 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:226]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu pptp[2665]: nm-pptp-service-2643 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:238]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu pptp[2673]: nm-pptp-service-2643 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:245]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu pptp[2673]: nm-pptp-service-2643 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:259]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu pptp[2673]: nm-pptp-service-2643 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:84]: Closing connection (call state)
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu NetworkManager[709]: <info>  [1605258602.8512] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Nov 13 01:10:02 ubuntu gnome-shell[1521]: Removing a network device that was not added
```

Can someone please tell me what issue is this and how to resolve it.

/Azeem

Comment: Does anyne face the same issue? if so, can someone please help me resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

PPTP may not be supported in virtual machines with certain network adapter types. E.g. in virtualbox pptp is not supported with NAT adapter.  You have to select bridged.  A comparable issue could exist in vmware.

Comment: How can I check if this is a case? I got the same issue here where I can see the receiving packets. https://superuser.com/questions/1687121/pptp-vpn-timeout-issue-on-debian-bullseye-hosted-on-qemu-kvm-with-nat-adapter

Comment: Can you switch to bridged in your setup? I only use virtualbox.  I found this link describing bridged for qemu/kvm : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-bridged-networking-with-libvirt-and-kvm

Answer (score 0):

The error message in your logs of `VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.` suggests that in attempting to connect to the VPN server, the connection timed out.

This means that either the device you're trying to connect to (VPN server) is offline and not web-reachable, or you have some type of proxy or firewall between you and the endpoint VPN server which is interfering.  (This could be at the VPN server side, the network side you're connected to, ISP filtering, or any number of things).

Unfortunately, debugging a *timeout* error is actually a lot harder than it sounds, so it's not really anything that can be solved here.  Even if you can ping the remote VPN server side that alone doesn't mean that the VPN connection itself is dead.

Also, as an IT Security guy, I have to suggest NOT using PPTP VPNs if you can avoid it.  PPTP VPNs, though common, have very weak levels of encryption and are fairly easy to break into from a security perspective.